# Trying to creating a temporary table in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create and populate a temporary table in a stored procedure.  But it throws error

> Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of

Here is my code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro_print_borrower
IS
days number := 0


DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp(Borrower_name varchar2(30) NOT NULL, Book_Title number NOT NULL, less_than equal_5days number,
    less_than equal_10days number,less_than equal_15days number,more_than_15days number)
on commit delete rows;

FOR O IN (SELECT BO.name , B.book_title, (current_date - I.issue_date) INTO days
          FROM Borrower BO,Issue I,Books B
          WHERE B0.borrower_id = I.borrower_id AND I.book_id = B.book_id;)

    IF (days <= 5) THEN
        INSERT INTO temp values(O.name,O.book_title,O.days,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    ELSIF(days <=10)
        INSERT INTO temp values(O.name,O.book_title,NULL,O.days,NULL,NULL);
    ELSIF(days <= 15)
        INSERT INTO temp values(O.name,O.book_title,NULL,NULL,O.days,NULL);
    ELSIF(days>15)
        INSERT INTO temp values(O.name,O.book_title,NULL,NULL,NULL,O.days);
    END IF;

END LOOPS;

SELECT *
FROM temp;

END ;

.
run;
```

Comment: First, put on your flame-retardant suit.  Second, edit the post and format it correctly, while actually asking a question.  Third, look for a syntax error on or before the line mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find the syntax `declare local temporary table...`?

Comment: new to oracle, misunderstood the concept slightly . thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like an attempt to translate MS T-SQL into Oracle PL/SQL.  Temporary tables don't work like that in Oracle, but there's generally no need for them anyway.

It's quite simple to implement your logic in pure Oracle SQL, using a sub-query factor clause (common table expression in MSSQL terms) and then a CASE statement to switch the columnn of the DAYS value.

```
with cte as (select bo.name 
                     , b.book_title
                     , (current_date - i.issue_date) as days
              from borrower bo,
                      issue i,
                      books b
              where b0.borrower_id = i.borrower_id 
              and i.book_id = b.book_id)
select cte.name as borrower_name
        , cte.book_title
        , case when (cte.days <= 5) then cte.days end as less_than equal_5days
        , case when (cte.days > 5 and cte.days <= 10) then cte.days end as less_than equal_10days
        , case when (cte.days > 10 and cte.days <= 15) then cte.days end as less_than equal_15days
        , case when (cte.days > 15) then cte.days end as more_than_15days
from cte
;
```

---

> "just display it on the screen"

So, to display stuff to the screen we can use DBMS_OUTPUT and call the code from an interactive client like SQL*Plus or TOAD.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm#ARPLS036)

So in your case we could run an anonymous block like this:

```
begin
    for rec in (
    with cte as (select bo.name 
                         , b.book_title
                         , (current_date - i.issue_date) as days
                  from borrower bo,
                          issue i,
                          books b
                  where b0.borrower_id = i.borrower_id 
                  and i.book_id = b.book_id)
    select cte.name as borrower_name
            , cte.book_title
            , case when (cte.days <= 5) then cte.days end as less_than equal_5days
            , case when (cte.days > 5 and cte.days <= 10) then cte.days end as less_than equal_10days
            , case when (cte.days > 10 and cte.days <= 15) then cte.days end as less_than equal_15days
            , case when (cte.days > 15) then cte.days end as more_than_15days
    from cte
    )
    loop
         dbms_output.put_line(rec.borrower_name
                              ||' '||rec.book_title
                              ||' '||lpad(to_char( rec.less_than equal_5days ), 6)
                              ||' '||lpad(to_char( rec.less_than equal_10days ), 6)
                              ||' '||lpad(to_char( rec.less_than equal_15days ), 6)
                              ||' '||lpad(to_char( rec.more_than_15days ), 6)
                          );
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: This will work, thanks
but the procedure which i am making is to print the output and as far as i know select statement , which is in procedure,doesnt print anything. So there was no point in making table if i cant print the result from SELECT *  FROM temp-table

Comment: You need to spell out your requirements.  When you say "print the output" what are you expecting?  How will your app call this code?

Comment: I have the database which consists of following table:
Author
Books
Borrower
Issue
Pending_request.

This procedure has to print the names of borrower in following format:
Borrower name, Book_title , no of days ( 4 coloumns of days , less than 5, less than 10, less than 15 and more than 15 )

I tried to make table but then again inside a procedure block no query prints the result, it doesnt mean query has didnt select any row. it might have or not.

Comment: Yes, yes.  My query does that.  Your previous comment seemed like a complaint.  Do you have any further requirements which my solution doesn't satisfy?

Comment: how will you output this table ? or print this table?

Comment: It depends on your application.  What sort of application is it?  How ill it call the code?

Comment: EXECUTE procedure-name; its in PL/SQL

Comment: So do you want a result set for consumption by some other program or just display to screen?   Please edit your question to state your complete requirement.  Honestly, if I'd have wanted to pull teeth I would have gone into dentistry.

Comment: just display it on the screen.
That comment was very encouraging!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in whcih language this code in question is asked. Its not purely Oracle as per the question. But still tried modifiying your code and provide you working code IN ORACLE as per requirement.Let me know if below code helps.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro_print_borrower
        IS
          days PLS_INTEGER := 0;
          lv_create_table_sql LONG;
          p_lst sys_refcursor;
        BEGIN

-- Why to create dynamically. Create it once and use it.

          lv_create_table_sql:= ' CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp    
                                  (Borrower_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,     
                                  Book_Title NUMBER NOT NULL,     
                                  less_than equal_5days NUMBER,     
                                  less_than equal_10days NUMBER,    
                                  less_than equal_15days NUMBER,    
                                  more_than_15days NUMBER    
                                  ) ON COMMIT    
                                  DELETE ROWS ';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_create_table_sql;

          FOR O IN
          (SELECT BO.name ,
            B.book_title,
            (CURRENT_DATE - I.issue_date)
          FROM Borrower BO,
            Issue I,
            Books B
          WHERE B0.borrower_id = I.borrower_id
          AND I.book_id        = B.book_id
          )
          LOOP
            IF (days <= 5) THEN
              INSERT INTO temp VALUES
                (O.name,O.book_title,O.days,NULL,NULL,NULL
                );
            ELSIF(days <=10) THEN
              INSERT INTO temp VALUES
                (O.name,O.book_title,NULL,O.days,NULL,NULL
                );
            ELSIF(days <= 15) THEN
              INSERT INTO temp VALUES
                (O.name,O.book_title,NULL,NULL,O.days,NULL
                );
            ELSIF(days>15) THEN
              INSERT INTO temp VALUES
                (O.name,O.book_title,NULL,NULL,NULL,O.days
                );
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
          OPEN p_lst FOR SELECT * FROM TEMP;
        END ;
```

Comment: thanks , i tried but i think there is a logical mistake in my code.
I want to check for each tuple in O whether days are less than this or that.
This code wont work for each tuple in 0? 
cursor would be a better option here

Comment: OK Can you please modify your question with what logic exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I have the database which consists of following table: Author Books Borrower Issue Pending_request. This procedure has to print the names of borrower in following format: Borrower name, Book_title , no of days ( 4 coloumns of days , less than 5, less than 10, less than 15 and more than 15 ) I tried to make table but then again inside a procedure block no query prints the result, it doesnt mean query has didnt select any row. it might have or not.

I am sorry for not being vague. new to this web. it wont allow me to question me more than 150 characters

Comment: no of days is the difference betwee the current date and issue date. so depends on this result we ll decide where to put the days in one of the 4 coloumns for days